# Best way to migrate CSV files to Django SQL back-end?

Tags: python, sql, django, csv, backend

I have a directory full of CSV files which I would like to use for the back-end of my Django web-app but I am struggling to populate my Django models with the data from the CSV files. This is because some of the files are .csv join tables connecting the other .csv files in the directory. When I try to map the relationships from the CSV files to the SQL  database I always run into problems.

Is there a better or more straight forward way of populating these models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an example below of loading in a fairly large dataset (entire USDA food nutrition database) from many CSV files that share IDs between them. But assuming that there is referential integrity in the CSV files (the IDs that cross reference between the CSV files are valid), it is a relatively straightforward approach.

https://github.com/pgalfi/homeapps/blob/master/foodtrack/management/commands/loadCSV.py

Could you share what problems you are running into with the relationships?

Comment: It turned out that I had actually already made the correct migration - I had been fooled by the Django Admin GUI which made it look like I had connected every parent entry to every child entry in the M2M relationship. Actually when I ran an objects.child.all() call, it revealed that only the selected entries which I had intended had been connected.